# how to update user in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to update user info and i am having error that it didn't get any data from my form

Here is my `user.controller`:

```
def update
    if !session[:id]
        redirect_to '/users'
    else
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @user.update(update_params)
        if @user.valid?
            @user.save
            redirect_to '/events'
        else
            flash[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
            redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}/edit"
        end
    end 
end


def update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:fname, :lname, :email, :city, :state)
end
```

edit update form
here is my `edit.html.erb` form:

```
   <form action="/users/<%= @user.id %>/update" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
        <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="fname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="user[fname]" class="form-control" placeholder="<%= @user.fname %>">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="lname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="user[lname]" class="form-control" placeholder="<%= @user.lname %>">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" name="user[email]" class="form-control" placeholder="<%= @user.email %>">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="location" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Location</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="text" name="user[city]" class="form-control" placeholder="<%= @user.city %>">

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <select class="custom-select" name="user[state]">
                    <%= options_for_select(us_states)%>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row clearfix">
            <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Update</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Just updated my html form

this is error in terminal when i hit submit from my form:

> (0.1ms)  begin transaction   User Exists (1.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one
>   FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'nhan13574@gmail.com' AND
>   "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1    (0.1ms)  rollback transaction Redirected
>   to http://localhost:4000/users/1/edit

Comment: What does your form look like? Add `puts params` at the top of the update action to debug what the params look like

Comment: Also, post the full error message.

Comment: @TomHarvey I just updated my form

Comment: @nathannewyen why are you using HTML `<form>` tag instead of Rails form helpers like `<%= form_tag %>` or `<%= form_with %>`?

Comment: Judging by the error message, you have a unique validation on user email, but you have 2 users in the database with the same email (maybe you added one with SQL?), which is why the update is failing (when you call `@user.valid?`). Just a hunch

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the form? mostly the issue is there.

Also, `@user.update` actually saves the data in db, no need to `save` after it.. here is a refactored version of your snippet:

```
def update
  return redirect_to '/users' unless session[:id]

  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(update_params)
     redirect_to '/events'
  else
     flash[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
     redirect_to "/users/#{@user.id}/edit"
  end
end
```